# Conexión SQL a WEB SERVICE

Tags: sql, sql-server, webservice

Necesito obtener la respuesta de un WEB SERVICE desde SQL, lo he realizado con éxito anteriormente, pero en esta caso no logro obtener más que un NULL, si pruebo la conexión a través de SOAP UI, me funciona perfectamente.

Les dejo el código SQL por si alguien me puede ayudar.

Se agradece

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Declare @sUrl varchar(max);
Declare @xmlString varchar (8000);
Declare @largo varchar (max);
Declare @SOAPAction varchar (max)

SET @xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <soap:Body>
                        <Login xmlns="Servicio">
                            <xmlString>
                                <![CDATA[ 
                                         <idCliente>usuario</idCliente>          
                                         <idUsuario>contraseña</idUsuario>
                                         <password>2</password>
                                    ]]>
                            </xmlString>
                        </Login>
                    </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>'

SET @largo = LEN(@xmlString)
SET @sUrl = 'https://34.200.104.163/CONTABWS/ContabService.svc?wsdl'
SET @SOAPAction = 'Servicio/Servicio/Login'

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @sUrl,'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object ,'setRequestHeader'    ,NULL ,'Host'           ,'34.200.104.163'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object ,'setRequestHeader'    ,NULL ,'Content-Type'   ,'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object ,'setRequestHeader'    ,NULL ,'Content-Length' ,@largo
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object ,'setRequestHeader'    ,NULL ,'SOAPAction',   @SOAPAction
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'                ,NULL, @xmlString
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
Exec sp_OADestroy @Object

Select @ResponseText
```